How to get the intended name of a referenced item?
I have an item labeled main_assmpt1 and named \textbf{(A)}.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{(A)}] \label{main_assmpt1}
abc
\begin{enumerate}
\item xyz.
\item pqr.
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

Our assumption is \hyperref[main_assmpt1]{\textbf{(A)}}.

\end{document} 

Can we have \textbf{(A)} when referring to main_assmpt1?

I can use \hyperref[main_assmpt1]{\textbf{(A)}} but this command is artificial and not flexible because we have already defined \item[\textbf{(A)}] \label{main_assmpt1}.
Thank you for your elaboration.

I have found the solution:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
  \item \label{main_assmpt1}
  abc
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item xyz.
    \item pqr.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Our assumption is \ref{main_assmpt1}

\end{document} 


I've taken the liberty of editing your code to simplify and streamline the preamble, to make it truly minimal with respect to the issue you were looking to solve. I've also changed [label=(A)] to [label=(\Alph*)], as otherwise any subsequent level-1 enumerated items will all be labeled "A". Feel free to revert.
